# Prove that the dual space of $\mathbb R^n$ is $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

I was going through the proof of this question in "***Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications" by Kreyszig***.

(Apologies for not being able to type the whole of it)

[image]

I got stuck after the line where we took the supremum over all x of norm 1.

> How did we arrive at the step of equality in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Any good explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just calculate it directly;
$$f(x)=\sum_k \xi_k\gamma_k = \sum_k \gamma_k\gamma_k = \sum_k \gamma_k^2=\left(\sum_k \gamma_k^2\right)^{\frac12}\cdot\left(\sum_k \gamma_k^2\right)^{\frac12}=\|x\|\cdot\left(\sum_k \gamma_k^2\right)^{\frac12}$$
since $\|x\|=\left(\sum_k\xi_k^2\right)^{\frac12} = \left(\sum_k\gamma_k^2\right)^{\frac12}$ when the $\xi$ and $\gamma$ are equal. It's not norm $1$, but we can just multiply by a constant for that.

Comment: How did you get $\sum_k \xi_k \gamma_k = \sum _k \gamma_k \gamma_k$?